# How to pass language to liferay using cas authentication

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6, cas

I had made some login page and using cas to authenticate and login to my liferay server. My integration works and I am able to login and access my liferay server. Now I am planning to give language selection in my login page so that user can select the language he need once after selection how can I pass this to liferay.

Answer (score 0):

Liferay accepts the language as the first path element in its URL - e.g. instead of redirecting to `www.example.com/web/guest/home`, direct to `www.example.com/es/web/guest/home`.

Alternatively, you can look into the different ways Liferay determines the language: Through Accept-Language browser headers, the user's profile, the global portal's default language.

Comment: By default I am redirecting to my service url c/portal/login I am not able to append the language to this url like es/c/portal/login or c/portal/login/es. So I am not able to pass the locale back to liferay